# Pre-defined point colours in seaboarn scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am doing scatterplots with seaborn and I want the points to have 'pre-defined' colours. I am looping though my dataframe and when I set `hue=df['category']`it uses the default palette. This is fine but I would like the categories to carry the same colour through each plot i.e if one category is not being plotted the colours do not change.

I thought I could use something like but it doesn't seem to work:

```
category_colour = {'Netflix':'Blue', 'TV':'Red', 'DVD':'Yellow', 'Radio':'Pink'}

plot = sns.scatterplot(x="Popularity", y="Likelihood", hue=colour, data=df)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you using `category_colour` to change `color`? Can you produce a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Did you read about `hue_order` argument? Did you consider using a `FacetGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
category_colour = {'Netflix':'Blue', 'TV':'Red', 'DVD':'Yellow', 'Radio':'Pink'}

plot = sns.scatterplot(x="Popularity", 
                       y="Likelihood", 
                       hue=df['category'].map(category_colour), 
                       data=df)
```

but make sure the colors in `category_colour` are valid.

Comment: Thats the one! I was missing `.map()`. Cheers legend